# Cloth simulation acts like the wind is blowing around her

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create cloth simulation, I've already avoided clothes clipping, but now it acts like there is a force field that blows on her (of cource there is no force). Maybe someone can help me to deal with it please?
Here you can see what is happening:

https://imgur.com/aDn4k2r

Also here is my settings to this cloth sim:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whan a mesh is dense, the distance values in the collisions tab are too big even at their lower values (0.001, like in your case).

The only way to solve that I know is to scale up the mesh, something like 10 times bigger, bake the simulation, and then rescale it down.

I wish this behaviour will be fixed someday.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @Alex if the answer is correct, mark it as correct   ;)