# My cloth simulation isn't working

Tags: animation, mesh, cloth-simulation, collision

I wanted a similar cloth effect like a sheet over a body in a morgue. I followed https://youtu.be/OguGDqf9xgs?si=WmELp_6FLgy-Ucb8 his tutorial to achieve a similar effect in which he used a grid as opposed to a plane. I failed dismally and then opted back to using a place but as soon as it lands on the collision object it always starts scrunching up and acting weird/clipping. Even though I turn on high quality steps and object collisions.

[image: scrunching cloth]
Help

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/307874/cloth-simulation-acts-like-the-wind-is-blowing-around-her/307882#307882